# Não consigo atualizar o estoque no Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento

Boa tarde,

Ao tentar atualizar o estoque, entrando no produto e mudando o valor no local especificado, a tela fica congelada e nada acontece.

A única coisa que fiz foi zerar a pasta cache e sessions, apenas por desencargo de consciência. Fora isso, nada fiz. Procurei no Google por alguma informação, sem sucesso.

Alguém já viu algo parecido? Como proceder?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vi que algumas atualizações estão prejudicando tarefas no Magento. Esta loja não teve atualizações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tela fica congelada com o Gif do aguarde? ... Dê uma olhada no console do navegador. Provavelmente é algum erro de JavaScript! Tive esse erro com uma das lojas que desenvolvi. No meu caso foi conflito com um módulo instalado. Descobri desativando o módulo em app/etc/modules/nomedomodulo.xml

Você pode renomear o módulo recentemente instalado para nomedomodulo.xml.disabled por exemplo. Sempre que instalar algo em sua loja e der algum tipo de erro, faça o teste para verificar se as funcionalidades voltam ao normal.

Também indico que você trabalhe em sua loja utilizando o GIT para versionamento. Caso não conheça, vale a pena gastar um tempinho para aprender. Pois com controle de versões, você pode simplesmente retornar até o momento que funcionava algo em sua loja, e assim descobrir entre as versões qual foi a alteração que causou tal erro.

Abraço